# Specifying MSBuild version with GitHub action

Tags: github, msbuild, github-actions

I'm trying to setup a GitHub workflow to compile a C++ Visual Studio 2019 solution, the default workflow could work but I'm linking against some libraries built with my MSVC version so I get the following error:

```
XXX was created by a different version of the compiler than other objects
```

which makes totally sense.

According to setup-msbuild action [it looks like](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-msbuild?version=v1.1) I can specify the version so I tried with

```
- name: Add MSBuild to PATH
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1
      with:
        vs-version: '[16.9, 16.10)'
```

but this is failing with

```
Run microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1
C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin\vswhere.exe -products * -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild -property installationPath -latest -version "[16.9, 16.10)"
Error: Unable to find MSBuild.
```

How am I supposed to solve this? If it's even possible

Comment: https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/release.ps1

Comment: Suspect only the latest version, Visual Studio 2022 (17.x), is available.  This runs fine without the `vs-version` option.  Try including `msbuild.exe -version` in your PowerShell script and you will see results similar to "MSBuild version 17.5.1+f6fdcf537 for .NET Framework".  Using a self-hosted runner with the appropriate Visual Studio release may be required.  The docs at https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-msbuild#specifying-specific-versions-of-visual-studio-optional only state you MAY have a situation where your Actions runner has multiple versions; no promises.